# How to find total number of values in a number range in a particular cell.?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For example:

DATA: 
**23 TO 26,
40,
22,
7,
27 TO 28,
49,
50 TO 51,
48,
136,
169,
190 TO 192,
17 TO 22**

I have these datas as shown above in each individual cell, how do I come up with a formula that sums up all the total number of values?

I need to do some updating of datas.

THANKS GUYS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for " - " or " TO ":

```
=ROWS(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," - ",":")," TO ", ":")))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks jerry, I still have an issue! Kindly assist me if you are free to do so. Thank you very much!
For example:

DATA: 23 TO 26, 40, 22, 7, 27 TO 28, 49, 50 TO 51, 48, 136, 169, 190 TO 192, 17 TO 22

I have these datas as shown above in each individual cell, how do I come up with a formula that sums up all the total number of values?

Comment: Would you be open to VBA?  I could create a User Defined Function that you could use in a cell like a normal function, it would go something like:  **=USERCOUNT(A1)**  Would that be ok? Not everyone like to use VBA.

Comment: I've created that UDF and posted it in your other thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9364330/1196002

Answer (score 0):

If your delimiter is '-' or 'TO' then split(Data -> Text to Columns) it into two columns and then use subtract between them.

Formula would be `=(B1-A1) + 1`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can directly use this formula:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1))*1 - LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1)*1 +1
```

And drag and drop it till the end of your values.