# How to find total number of values in a number range in a particular cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For example:

**DATA COLUMN: 23 TO 26, 40, 22, 7, 27 TO 28, 49, 50 TO 51, 48, 136, 169, 190 TO 192, 17 TO 22 AND NIL**

*includes individual numbers, number range and word.

I have these datas as shown above in each individual cell, how do I come up with a formula that sums up all the total number of values?

I need to do some updating of datas.

I am currently using a formula provided by *Jerry Beaucaire*:

```
=ROWS(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," - ",":")," TO ", ":")))
```

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you just sum up the values found in your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357232 (i.e. sum the results of the formula in the other column)

Comment: are you looking for a COUNT or a SUM? For example from 23 To 26 do you want an answer of 4...or an answer of 23+24+25+26 = 98?

Comment: @barryhoudini: actually, this question is the second part of user1220400's previous question (you can find the link in my first comment)

Comment: @barryhoudini, I am looking for a COUNT. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula based on `JMAX's` approach

`=SUM(IF(ISERR(FIND("TO",A1:A6)),ISNUMBER(A1:A6)+0,MID(A1:A6,FIND("TO",A1:A6)+2,9)-LEFT(A1:A6,FIND("TO",A1:A6)-1)+1))`

confirmed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`

assumes delimiter is "TO" as per your examples

Revised approach:

FIND is case-sensitive, SEARCH is not, so to allow "TO" or "to" you can change all instances of FIND to SEARCH. The following version will therefore cope with either of those, blank cells, cells with "Nil", cells with entries such as 23, 24, 27 (counted as 3) or 11 & 99 (counted as 2) or cells with a single number like 33 (counted as 1)

`=SUM(IF(ISERR(SEARCH("TO",A1:A6)),IF((A1:A6="Nil")+(A1:A6=""),0,LEN(A1:A6)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A6,",",""),"&",""))+1),MID(A1:A6,SEARCH("TO",A1:A6)+2,9)-LEFT(A1:A6,SEARCH("TO",A1:A6)-1)+1))`

Revision no 2

Assuming data in A1:A22

`=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(LEFT(A1:A22)+0),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("to",A1:A22)),MID(A1:A22,SEARCH("TO",A1:A22)+2,9)-LEFT(A1:A22,SEARCH("TO",A1:A22)-1)+1,LEN(A1:A22)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A22,",",""),"&",""))+1)))`

Comment: Awesome, Barry, just awesome!

Comment: Thank you very much Barry! It's awesome! However can I get the formula to recognise the delimiter as TO and to together? Also will it be able to count the values if one of my cell contains '150 & 152' or '150, 152'? THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: @user1220400 OK, edited my suggestion above to include those options

Comment: However I tried with your revised approach and these are my data: cancelled, 23 TO 26, cancelled, confo, cancelled, dup, 40, 22, 7, 27 TO 28, 2, 50 TO 51, 48, transfer, duplicate, 136, not for rc, not for rc, 165, duplicate, cancelled, 169 & 180. With the revised approach forumula the answer i got was 28 (this includes all cells), however what I hope to get is only cells that have numbers in them :) Is it able to do so?
It should have a answer of 17.

Comment: thank you very much. works perfectly fine. What if one of my data cell contains, '27 to 28 & 42 to 45 & 48 to 49'? The answer should be 8

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only one cell to calculate the whole results, you can use this one (based on my solution because the `INDIRECT` wouldn't work there):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(ISERR(FIND("-",A1:A6)),
MID(A1:A6,FIND("TO",A1:A6)+2,LEN(A1:A6))*1-LEFT(A1:A6,FIND("TO",A1:A6)-1)*1+1,
MID(A1:A6,FIND("-",A1:A6)+1,LEN(A1:A6))*1-LEFT(A1:A6,FIND("-",A1:A6)-1)*1+1)
)
```

Comment: thank you very much JMax! However I don't get the correct answers :(
I wanna try to do all in one step, however I know this is very tough. 
I can sum up the values however, I would have to identify those cells that have number range and apply the appropriate formula. Is there any automatic method if I were to sum up the results?

Comment: In some version, you may have to validate the formula as an array formula with Ctrl - Shift - Enter. Tell me what doesn't work if it still doesn't.

Comment: I tried going into the formula and clicking on array and Ctrl Shift Enter, an error occurs. 
Let's say i were to use the indirect(substitute method by Jerry, I could not drag it down and sum them together because there will be a #REF! error on those individual number or word cells. Is there any way to go around it? 

Thank you very much JMax!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single formula to collect these values from a range of cells, I would write a new custom function for this.  This is how i would do that...

***How to install the User Defined Function:***

1. Open up your workbook
2. Get into VB Editor ***(Press Alt+F11)***
3. Insert a new module ***(Insert > Module)***
4. Copy and Paste in your code *(given below)*
5. Get out of VBA ***(Press Alt+Q)***
6. Save as a macro-enabled workbook

The function is installed and ready to use.

Here's the UDF code for a new function called **USERCOUNT()***

```
Option Explicit

Function USERCOUNT(RNG As Range) As Long
Dim cell As Range, Cnt As Long, c As Long, buf As String

    For Each cell In RNG
        If IsNumeric(cell) And cell > 0 Then
            Cnt = Cnt + 1
        ElseIf InStr(1, cell, ",") > 0 Or InStr(1, cell, "&") > 0 Then
            Cnt = Cnt + (Len(cell) - Len(Replace(Replace(cell, ",", ""), "&", "")) + 1)
        ElseIf InStr(1, cell, " TO ") > 0 Or InStr(1, cell, " - ") > 0 Then
            buf = Replace(Replace(cell, " TO ", ":"), " - ", ":")
            Cnt = Cnt + Rows(buf).Rows.Count
            buf = ""
        End If
    Next cell

    USERCOUNT = Cnt

End Function
```

That is simply used in a cell like a normal function referencing a range of cell:

[image: USERCOUNT.JPG]

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH JERRY! I have one more issue. How do I do proper referencing using the indirect function so that I could drag the user count formula that extracts data from various worksheet on the same workbook. Cheers!

Comment: Ignore my previous question  I solved it. THANK YOU VERY MUCH JERRY! I have one more issue. What happens if one of my data cell contains '140, 142' or '140 & 142'. The answer value should be 2. Cheers!

Comment: This is called "feature creep" and you should keep it from happening.  Control how your users (or yourself) are allowed to enter values and you won't have to keep editing your functions.   Meanwhile, I've added these last two additions as an feature in the macro above. hoping for at least an up vote... ;)